# Excel VBA autofill across and down

Tags: vba, excel, fill, autofill

Ok... I am struggling with something that is probably simple... I have a formula in cell B2 and I want to fill to the last cell that contains data or formatting (same as when you press CTRL+END) or in other words "the bottom right corner" of my data. How do I do this? There is data in column "A" and in row "1"... So it needs to fill to the last row and last column containing data...

```
lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range("B2"), Cells(2, lastCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("B2:B" & lastCol).AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2"), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: Record a macro and it will give you the VBA.

Comment: I did... and control + end gives "ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select" but... Like I said I have been struggling trying to make it work...

Comment: Are you getting some error or something? You aren't explaining the issue very well.

Comment: Watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  `ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select` will select the last cell of the `ActiveCell`.  `ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)` will return the last cell of the `ActiveSheet`.  In anycase, watch the video.

Comment: The issue is I don't know how to do it... 99% of every Google search I have tried refers to filling down a single column to the last used row... a few refer to filling a known range down a column to the last used row... and a few refer to filling a known range across to the last used column... but I cant find how to fill down to the last used row and the last used column... say... column a has numbers 1 through 10 and row 1 has numbers 1 through 10 and cell b2 has $A2*B$1... I want to auto fill this formula to make a multiplication chart like is used in elementary school

Comment: and just to be clear... this is a simplified example... in reality... I have dates in column A and names in row 1... and my formula is a sumifs... but the simplified example of the multiplication chart will work if I can figure out how to fill to the last used row and last used column....

Comment: lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column......
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row..........
    Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range("B2"), Cells(2, lastCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault..........
    Range("B2:B" & lastCol).AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2"), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Comment: that is what I had tried last but it didn't work... ive been trying different things for hours

Comment: Are you getting errors? Incorrect results, etc? How isn't it working? Also can you please edit the code into the original post? Thanks.

Comment: ok I added the code into the original post

Comment: basically I was trying to fill across then select it all and fill down... but It didn't work and I don't know if I can simplify it by telling it to fill from B2 to "ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select"...

Comment: do you understand?

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code helps you determine, and reference, your "box range." The code is making 3 assumptions that you may need to amend for if incorrect:

1) The "top left corner" of your box range is B2

2) Values in Col B span to the bottom of your range. If you expect blanks in Col B, change this to a different column.

3) Values in row 2 span to the end of your used columns. If you expect blanks in row 2, change this to a different row.

```
Sub RangeBox()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Dim LRow As Long
Dim LCol As Long

LRow = WS.Range("B" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LCol = WS.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

MsgBox "Last Row: " & LRow & vbNewLine & "Last Column: " & LCol

'How to refer to the box range starting from A1
Dim Start As Range
Set Start = WS.Range("B2")

WS.Range(Start, WS.Cells(LRow, LCol)).Select

End Sub
```

To fill this range with a formula:

```
WS.Range(Start, WS.Cells(LRow, LCol)).Formula = "=Sum(1,2)"
```

Inside the quotes, type the equation in as you would in excel and used locked references if needed ($). The above example would fill your range with the value 3.

Comment: This doesn't quite work... But its much closer to working than I have ever been before... this starts at cell "B2" and fills left and up to "A1"... if I change -->Set Start = WS.Range("B2")-->Set Start = WS.Range("E10")-->then it starts at cell "E10" and fills left and up to "A1"... is there a way to tell it to fill down and to the right? Otherwise is there a way to change --> Set Start = WS.Range("B2") --> to reference the cell (LCol, LRow)

Comment: wait a min... its doing that because it is determining my last row as 1 and my last column as 1... it wasn't doing that the first few times I ran it... hmmm... let me see if I can figure it out... I bet its because A1 is now blank...

Comment: no... I thought A1 was blank, but its not... I don't know why it is saying row 1 col 1 for last cell...

Comment: ok... figured it out... your formula is looking at row 2 and column B which in my case... the only rows/columns with data are row 1 and column A... after changing LRow and LCol to "A" and "1"... it works... thank you so much!!

Comment: Ok!! At last!! So my formula worked in excel but not in visual basic... Turns out that it was because I had a criteria for sumifs that was "="&A2 and in VBA you have to use double quotes ""=""&A2... Here is my formula --> WS.Range("B2", WS.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Formula = "=SUMIFS(Raw_Data!$F$2:$F$1000,Raw_Data!$A$2:$A$1000,""=""&Matrix!$A2,Raw_Data!$E$2:$E$1000,""=""&Matrix!B$1)"